# Retrieving data from Strapi v4 and mapping it in ReactJS just returns empty array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, strapi

I am trying to map data from Strapi, but receiving an empty array. The endpoint works fine through  Postman:
[image]

the custom useFetch just not working:

```
const useFetch = (url) => {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [error, setError] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      setLoading(true);

      try {
        const res = await fetch(url);
        const json = await res.json();
        setData(json);
        setLoading(false);
      } catch (error) {
        setError(error);
        setLoading(false);
      }
    };

    fetchData();
  }, [url]);

  return { loading, error, data };
};

export default useFetch;
```

The Homepage.js component:

```
import useFetch from "../hooks/useFetch";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

export default function Homepage() {
  const { loading, error, data } = useFetch("http//localhost:1337/api/recepts");

  if (loading) {
    return <p>Loading...</p>;
  } else if (error === []) {
    return <p>Error</p>;
  }

  return (
    <div>
      {Array.isArray(data) &&
        data?.map((el) => (
          <div key={data.id} className="recept-card">
            <h2>{data.data.attributes.title}</h2>

            <small>console list</small>

            <p>{data.data.attributes.body.substring(0, 200)}</p>
            <Link to={`/details/${data.data.id}`}>...</Link>
          </div>
        ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

I don't receive any errors, just empty arrays when logging to the console. I would appreciate any ideas to correct this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you should use `el` instead of `data` inside the map returned JSX.

```
      {Array.isArray(data) &&
        data?.map((el) => (
          <div key={el.id} className="recept-card">
            <h2>{el.attributes.title}</h2>

            <small>console list</small>

            <p>{el.attributes.body.substring(0, 200)}</p>
            <Link to={`/details/${el.id}`}>...</Link>
          </div>
        ))}
```

Comment: Yes, I just figured it out the other day.